# replace captured spaces an unknown number of times with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a regex that matches the city/state formats `The City, ST` pattern with the consideration that some towns have multiple words in their names, how can I reduce them to this format?

```
new_town_city_st
```

My expression:  `/(\w+(\s))*(\w+)(,\s)(\w{2})/`

How can I replace where I have captures (spaces) with underscores when I don't know how many words each town name will be?

Comment: Should the end format be in lower case or was that just an example?

Comment: @acdcjunior lowercase, but that's simple thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace all repeated non-word characters (`\W`) with an underscore as follows:

```
var locationInput = 'New Town City, ST';

var underscoreLocation = function(location) {
    return location.replace(/\W+/ig, '_').toLowerCase();
};

var locationOutput = underscoreLocation(locationInput);
// => new_town_city_st
```

Answer (score 0):

`myString=myString.replace(/,\s*|\s+/g,'_');`

edited to throw comma into the mix

edit: your post didn't explicitly say it but if you wanted it to be lower cased:

`myString=myString.replace(/,\s*|\s+/g,'_').toLowerCase();`